# installing rmagick gem on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, rmagick

So I have been searching around for a while and I was finally able to get `gem install rmagick` to get past one second of time before erroring out. I had to get an older version of imageMagick installer `6.8.8-0-Q16` than imageMagick has hosted on their site right now because it did not have the option to install dev c/c++ headers and I have been working hard to get things working this is the out put from my last run of gem install.

```
C:\Sites>gem install rmagick
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for snprintf() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for AcquireImage() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... no
checking for AffinityImage() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... no
checking for AffinityImages() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... no
checking for AutoGammaImageChannel() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... no
checking for AutoLevelImageChannel() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... no
checking for BlueShiftImage() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... no
checking for ConstituteComponentTerminus() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... no
checking for DeskewImage() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... no
checking for EncipherImage() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... no
checking for EqualizeImageChannel() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... no
checking for FloodfillPaintImage() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... no
checking for FunctionImageChannel() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... no
checking for GetAuthenticIndexQueue() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... no
checking for GetAuthenticPixels() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... no
checking for GetImageAlphaChannel() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... no
checking for GetVirtualPixels() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... no
checking for LevelImageColors() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... no
checking for LevelColorsImageChannel() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... no
checking for LevelizeImageChannel() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... no
checking for LiquidRescaleImage() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... no
checking for MagickLibAddendum() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for OpaquePaintImageChannel() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... no
checking for QueueAuthenticPixels() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... no
checking for RemapImage() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... no
checking for RemoveImageArtifact() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... no
checking for SelectiveBlurImageChannel() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... no
checking for SetImageAlphaChannel() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... no
checking for SetImageArtifact() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... no
checking for SetMagickMemoryMethods() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... no
checking for SparseColorImage() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... no
checking for SyncAuthenticPixels() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... no
checking for TransformImageColorspace() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... no
checking for TransparentPaintImage() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... no
checking for TransparentPaintImageChroma() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... no
checking for QueryMagickColorname() new signature... yes
checking for Image.type in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for DrawInfo.kerning in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for DrawInfo.interline_spacing in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for DrawInfo.interword_spacing in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for DitherMethod in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for MagickFunction in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for ImageLayerMethod in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for long double in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for AlphaChannelType.CopyAlphaChannel... yes
checking for AlphaChannelType.BackgroundAlphaChannel... yes
checking for CompositeOperator.BlurCompositeOp... yes
checking for CompositeOperator.DistortCompositeOp... yes
checking for CompositeOperator.LinearBurnCompositeOp... yes
checking for CompositeOperator.LinearDodgeCompositeOp... yes
checking for CompositeOperator.MathematicsCompositeOp... yes
checking for CompositeOperator.PegtopLightCompositeOp... yes
checking for CompositeOperator.PinLightCompositeOp... yes
checking for CompositeOperator.VividLightCompositeOp... yes
checking for CompressionType.DXT1Compression... yes
checking for CompressionType.DXT3Compression... yes
checking for CompressionType.DXT5Compression... yes
checking for CompressionType.ZipSCompression... yes
checking for CompressionType.PizCompression... yes
checking for CompressionType.Pxr24Compression... yes
checking for CompressionType.B44Compression... yes
checking for CompressionType.B44ACompression... yes
checking for DistortImageMethod.BarrelDistortion... yes
checking for DistortImageMethod.BarrelInverseDistortion... yes
checking for DistortImageMethod.BilinearForwardDistortion... yes
checking for DistortImageMethod.BilinearReverseDistortion... yes
checking for DistortImageMethod.DePolarDistortion... yes
checking for DistortImageMethod.PolarDistortion... yes
checking for DistortImageMethod.PolynomialDistortion... yes
checking for DistortImageMethod.ShepardsDistortion... yes
checking for DitherMethod.NoDitherMethod... yes
checking for FilterTypes.KaiserFilter... yes
checking for FilterTypes.WelshFilter... yes
checking for FilterTypes.ParzenFilter... yes
checking for FilterTypes.LagrangeFilter... yes
checking for FilterTypes.BohmanFilter... yes
checking for FilterTypes.BartlettFilter... yes
checking for FilterTypes.SentinelFilter... yes
checking for MagickEvaluateOperator.PowEvaluateOperator... yes
checking for MagickEvaluateOperator.LogEvaluateOperator... yes
checking for MagickEvaluateOperator.ThresholdEvaluateOperator... yes
checking for MagickEvaluateOperator.ThresholdBlackEvaluateOperator... yes
checking for MagickEvaluateOperator.ThresholdWhiteEvaluateOperator... yes
checking for MagickEvaluateOperator.GaussianNoiseEvaluateOperator... yes
checking for MagickEvaluateOperator.ImpulseNoiseEvaluateOperator... yes
checking for MagickEvaluateOperator.LaplacianNoiseEvaluateOperator... yes
checking for MagickEvaluateOperator.MultiplicativeNoiseEvaluateOperator... yes
checking for MagickEvaluateOperator.PoissonNoiseEvaluateOperator... yes
checking for MagickEvaluateOperator.UniformNoiseEvaluateOperator... yes
checking for MagickEvaluateOperator.CosineEvaluateOperator... yes
checking for MagickEvaluateOperator.SineEvaluateOperator... yes
checking for MagickEvaluateOperator.AddModulusEvaluateOperator... yes
checking for MagickFunction.ArcsinFunction... yes
checking for MagickFunction.ArctanFunction... yes
checking for MagickFunction.PolynomialFunction... yes
checking for MagickFunction.SinusoidFunction... yes
checking for ImageLayerMethod.FlattenLayer... yes
checking for ImageLayerMethod.MergeLayer... yes
checking for ImageLayerMethod.MosaicLayer... yes
checking for ImageLayerMethod.TrimBoundsLayer... yes
checking for VirtualPixelMethod.HorizontalTileVirtualPixelMethod... yes
checking for VirtualPixelMethod.VerticalTileVirtualPixelMethod... yes
checking for VirtualPixelMethod.HorizontalTileEdgeVirtualPixelMethod... yes
checking for VirtualPixelMethod.VerticalTileEdgeVirtualPixelMethod... yes
checking for VirtualPixelMethod.CheckerTileVirtualPixelMethod... yes
checking for ruby/io.h... yes
checking for rb_frame_this_func() in ruby.h,ruby/io.h... yes
creating extconf.h
creating Makefile


======================================================================
Sun 05Jan14 20:21:14
This installation of RMagick 2.13.2 is configured for
Ruby 1.9.3 (i386-mingw32) and ImageMagick 6.8.8
======================================================================



make
generating RMagick2-i386-mingw32.def
compiling rmagick.c
In file included from rmagick.c:13:0:
rmagick.h:81:2: error: #error Specified QuantumDepth is not supported.
rmagick.c: In function 'Magick_colors':
rmagick.c:42:5: warning: passing argument 2 of 'GetColorInfoList' from incompatible pointer type
C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.8.8-Q16\include/magick/color.h:75:5: note: expected 'size_t *' but argument is of type 'long unsigned int *'
rmagick.c: In function 'Magick_fonts':
rmagick.c:90:5: warning: passing argument 2 of 'GetTypeInfoList' from incompatible pointer type
C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.8.8-Q16\include/magick/type.h:98:5: note: expected 'size_t *' but argument is of type 'long unsigned int *'
rmagick.c: In function 'Magick_init_formats':
rmagick.c:178:5: warning: passing argument 2 of 'GetMagickInfoList' from incompatible pointer type
C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.8.8-Q16\include/magick/magick.h:129:5: note: expected 'size_t *' but argument is of type 'long unsigned int *'
make: *** [rmagick.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rmagick-2.13.2 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rmagick-2.13.2/ext/RMagick/gem_make.out
```

Any help would be much appreciated because I'm not sure what to do from here.

Comment: I see lots of no's in the check, perhaps you forgot to add the include/ and lib/ directories to CPATH and LIBRARY_PATH respectively

Comment: I did add them but I had to create those as variables because I'm on win 8.1 not sure if they should have been there before because this is my first time trying to get it on windows. If you look farther down you will notice `C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.8.8-Q16\include/magick/color.h:75:5: note: expected 'size_t *' but argument is of type 'long unsigned int *'` so it is finding `CPATH` at least

Comment: this one is a warning, is there anything that has error in front of it?

Comment: `rmagick.h:81:2: error: #error Specified QuantumDepth is not supported.`

Comment: it seems that the env var `QuantumDepth` isn't 8/16/32/64, supported by the `rmagick`. You need to know, which value has the `QuantumDepth` var. Try `-E` key of `gcc` compiler to generate expanded c file to know the value. and see **ext/RMagick/rmagick.h** for details

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had this problem a few days ago and I solved it by following a bunch of tutorials.

In short, your error seems to be due to a compatibility problem between your ImageMagic and Rmagick.

Uninstall ImageMagick and re-install a previous version that works with your Ruby setup.

This is what worked for me :

- Ruby 1.9.3
- Dev Kit 32-4.5.2
- ImageMagick 6.7.7 (I had a really hard time finding binary versions for legacy versions of ImageMagick so i guess [this link](http://ftp.icm.edu.pl/packages/ImageMagick/binaries/) will be handy for you)
- Rmagick 2.13.2

Comment: ImageMagick **6.7.9-9** also works fine, but the latest 6.8.8 doesn't.

Comment: `6.8.7.8` works, but `6.8.7.9` fails. It looks like `6.8.7.8` is the latest version works with `rmagick` in windows. I found the info from here http://www.ownway.info/Ruby/index.php?rmagick%2Fhowtoinstall%2Fwindows *Only in Japanese*, and checked it myself.

Comment: I can confirm that Tetsu's information is correct as of rmagick v2.13.3